# iframe not working wp rest api json angular2

Tags: json, wordpress, angular, rest

in wordpress rest API have values like

```
    "content": {
  "rendered": "<div class=\"pro-info\">\n<p>Villes &amp; Paysages, an Egis Group subsidiary, is an urban planning and design agency for public spaces. Their approach is based on the creation of favorable conditions for the expression of bodies in motion: to create an urban composition capable of transcending technical standards, management of flows, integration of infrastructures, economic dynamics &#8230; Villes &amp; Paysages asked us to rethink their visual identity as well as their website.</p>\n<p><img src=\"http://dev.twinsway.com/ty001/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/pr2-6.jpg\" alt=\"\" /></p>\n</div>\n<p><iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/rHmk0UhJSb4\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>\n"
```

and my angular code is like

```
<div class="container">
    <div [innerHTML]="singleDetails.content.rendered"> </div>
    </div>
```

all other divs are working fine. but iframe not working in angular2. 
please help me.
thanks in advance

Comment: any error in the dev console ?

Comment: no console error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
<div class="container">
  <div [innerHTML]="singleDetails?.content?.rendered"> </div>
</div>
```

also try print simply in HTML to be sure whether data is coming in view part or not like this

```
{{singleDetails?.content?.rendered}}
```

Comment: have you tried to print in the HTML part like in second example of my answer ?

Comment: @ShanaRaj can you reproduce your problem on plunker ?